Custom button in the block editor inserter button ("Add block" button)
How can I list/log all JS hooks (actions/filters) in gutenberg editor?
Basically I want to understand if the .block-editor-inserter container has any actions or hooks (@wordpress/hooks) to make changes there. Because this section is toggled - removed and re-appeared on new block insertion action.
I checked this article
